# Quelle préposition quand un verbe peut être suivi de plusieurs ?

Tags: prépositions, verbes

Je voudrais saisir le principe sous-jacent à la distinction entre « ôter à » et « ôter de ». Par l'utilisateur Jab' dans [cette question de Wordreference.com](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2551121&p=12855379#post12855379),

> J'aurais tendance à dire que "ôter"
>   au sens propre (retirer physiquement) => ôter de,
>   alors que "retirer" au sens figuré (non-physique) => ôter à.

Est-ce vrai globalement quand un verbe peut être suivi de plus d'une préposition ? Que glaner de ce cas ? Y a-t-il d'autres verbes qui suivent le même schéma de prépositions.

Answer (score 5):

Il me semble qu'une nuance existe en effet entre *ôter de* et *ôter à* :

- *« ôter [objet 1] **de** [objet 2] »* a plus souvent un sens spatial et concret : on sort un objet d'un ensemble localisé dans l'espace.

  > ôter un fruit **du** panier
- *« ôter [objet 1] **à** [objet 2] »*, a habituellement un sens abstrait, exprimant plutôt le fait de retirer une qualité ou caractéristique à un objet.

  > Ça n'ôte rien **à** votre courage.

---

En revanche, il me semble périlleux d'y chercher une règle qui s'applique aux autres verbes acceptant plusieurs prépositions. La manière dont un verbe délivre un ou plusieurs sens, ainsi que les variations apportées par les différentes prépositions utilisables avec ce verbe, sont des données linguistiques résultant de l'usage, et non pas les conséquences d'une règle stricte et identifiable. Votre curiosité est légitime, la question est intéressante, mais je doute qu'il y ait une réponse qui épuise le sujet sans établir une immense typologie pleine d'exceptions...

Answer (score 3):

Personnellement,

> ôter [objet 1] de [objet 2]

Le second objet est considéré comme une collection dont on enlève un élément. (*J’ôte une couverture du lit.*)

> ôter [objet 1] à [objet 2]

Le second objet est considéré comme tout que l'on dissocie. (*J’ôte un pied au lit.*)

Comment: « Ote-toi de là! », c'est enlever un élément à une collection ? Ta distinction me semble étrange. Cela dit, après réflexion, ce n'est peut-être qu'une question d'intuition linguistique, et un seul contre-exemple comme celui que je citais n'invalide pas ton propos. A approfondir...

Comment: @RomainVALERI, C'est en effet plutôt une intuition dont je n'ai pas chercher à approfondir la formulation.  Mais ton exemple n'en invalide pas le fond. Si je m'ôte de là, je ne touche pas à l’intégrité (physique ou symbolique) du lieu, comme quand j’ôte un pied au lit ou un enfant à sa mère.

Comment: +1. Pour moi (un anglophone), "oter de" signifie d'enlever un element d'un ensemble d'elements, tandis que "oter a" signifie plutot de soustraire (ou abstraire) un attribue ou une propriete ou une partie d'un object.